# How can I get store id in the bigcommerce theme?

Tags: bigcommerce

I need the store id for an external js script that will be put in the theme's header and try to find the store based on this id (on our side).

Answer (score 0):

If just trying to grab it manually, you can find it by logging in to the store. The URL will be https://store-XXXXXX.mybigcommerce.com/admin. XXXXXX is the store ID.

If trying to get it via the API, you will want to use the Store resource (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/store_information).

Comment: I kind of expect a variable like the ones from the bigcommerce themes with %% or something like that, because in this js script, the id has to be dynamically retrieved since this script will be on multiple bigcommerce stores

Comment: I've added another answer - it explains how to get StoreID via Javascript

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any supported way how to get Store ID.

Unsupported way (which theoretically can break anytime, but I believe it should work for quite long time) is to get it in Javascript from `Fornax.configuration.defaultEventProperties.storeId` variable.